# Execution error in c: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: c, input, segmentation-fault, scanf

I'm just a beginner as programmer in C. Trying to do a basic program and this error appears when I execute and introduce whichever number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
  float a;
  scanf("%f",a);
  printf("%f\n",a);
  return (0);
}
```

Comment: And turn up your compiler warning levels. Ex: appropriately configured, clang shows: "main.c:5:16: Format specifies type 'float *' but the argument has type 'double'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember scanf is a function, the problem you are having is passing the variable directly. By doing so the program will receive a copy of the variable and will not be able to modify the one contained in main.
Scanf works with pointers to data types, thats why you need to pass a pointer. 
This should fix it:

> scanf("%f",&a);

Note :When using the & you're using the memory position of that variable(the same thing as a pointer).

The reason why you're getting a seg fault is that inside scanf once the function picks up the user input it will do something along the lines of

```
*a = user_input;//suppose the user_input was a float(already converted from a string)
```

If you pass the variable directly it will try to deference the value contained.

Comment: I think I got it but.. in this code why dont we need to put '&' ?, the program works fine indeed: { char str1[20], str2[30];

   printf("Enter name: ");
   scanf("%s", str1);

   printf("Enter your website name: ");
   scanf("%s", str2);

   printf("Entered Name: %s\n", str1);
   printf("Entered Website:%s", str2);
   
   return(0); }

Comment: Remember that when declaring char str1[20];  str1 is the label of an array which functions very similar to a pointer, only that you may not modify str1. When passing str1 to scanf it's the same as passing &str1[0], which would be the memory position where the array starts or a "pointer" to the array

Comment: If my answer helped out consider accepting[link] my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` expects the *address* of the variable `a`; what you're actually passing is the *contents* of the variable `a`, which is a) *indeterminate*<sup>1</sup>, and b) very likely not a valid<sup>2</sup> address.

You need to use the unary `&` operator to obtain the *address* of `a`:

```
scanf( "%f", &a );
```

The exception to this rule is when you are reading a string and storing it to an array of `char`; arrays are special, and under most circumstances an array expression is treated *as though* it were a pointer to the first element of the array, so when reading strings of text, you would do something like the following:

```
char str[N]; // for some size N
scanf ("%s", str ); // no & for array parameters
```

---

<sup>1. Unless it's declared at file scope (outside the body of any function) or with the `static` keyword, a variable will not be initialized to any particular value; its contents will be random garbage.  

2.  In this case, "valid" means the address of a variable in your program.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is here :

```
scanf("%f",a);
```

it should be :

```
scanf("%f",&a);
```

According to man :

> The scanf() family of functions scans input according to format as described below. This format may contain conversion specifications; the results from such conversions, if any, are **stored in the locations pointed to by the pointer arguments that follow format**. Each pointer argument must be of a type that is appropriate for the value returned by the corresponding conversion specification.